# How do you right align in itemize without adding space?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, enumitem, ragged2e

How do I make my text after the linebreak right aligned while making it's top and bottom margin the same as topsep

Example of code:

```
Các nội dung nêu trên nhằm nổi bật một quan điểm tổng quát: từ ngữ Hán Việt là kết quả của sự tiếp nhận tiếng Hán mang \emph{tính sáng tạo} của người Việt Nam trong quá trình phát triển tiếng Việt.

\begin{itemize}
    \item Chương 1: Những cơ sở lý thuyết về từ ngoại lai\\
        \begin{FlushRight}
            Lý Toàn Thắng, Phạm Hùng Việt
        \end{FlushRight}
    \item Chương 2: Yếu tố Hán Việt - tiếp nhận và sáng tạo
        \begin{FlushRight}
            Lê Xuân Thại
        \end{FlushRight}
    \item Chương 3: Từ ghép Hán Việt - tiếp nhận và sáng tạo
        \begin{FlushRight}
            Lê Xuân Thại
        \end{FlushRight}
    \item Chương 4: 
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Please post a complete example rather than mere fragments of code. It's impossible to know what this code produces without knowing how the environments you're using are defined. Class, relevant packages etc. But you should never use `\\ ` to end a line except in special contexts. So using it in the first `\item` is a mistake. (Unless, of course, this fragment is embedded in a special context ....)